# Testing with paper_trail with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I am trying an example using paper_trail v2.6.3 in Rails 3 by following the [Github Documentation for paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). I want to write a spec for a model that lets me check if its versioned under paper_trail something like:

```
it { should be_trailed }
```

and be_trailed should be a custom rspec matcher that should check if the model is versioned or not.

How do I write the spec?

*P.S. I do not want to revert versions. I just want to check if its versioned.*

I am using it on the demo_app following Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to write RSpec matchers, the documentation is [here](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/custom-matchers).

If you're asking what the matcher should do, you could try checking to see if the object responds to the methods provided by paper_trail.  For example

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_trailed do
  match do |actual|
    actual.respond_to?(:versions)
  end
end
```

Comment: So here, where you mentioned `actual.respond_to?(:versions)`, I can write methods like `:previous_version`, `:next_version` or any of the other methods in the doc given, right?

Answer (score 2):

## Shared Contexts

I personally like to test that my models are including PaperTrail via Rspec's shared contexts, like so:

#### ./spec/support/shared_contexts/paper_trail_contexts.rb

```
shared_context 'a PaperTrail model' do
  it { should respond_to(:versions) }

  # You can add other assertions here as well if you like.
end
```

#### ./spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
it_behaves_like 'a PaperTrail model'
```

#### Rspec output

```
User
  behaves like a PaperTrail model
    should respond to #versions
```

I find this clearer and more expandable then using a custom matcher, like `be_trailed`.